# How can I remove the question mark ? in JS and CSS path to files in Ruby on Rails 2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

I'm trying to optimize the performance of our web app, but I just found that by running [PageTest](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) in our web site one of the recommendations says:

Resources with a "?" in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching servers. Remove the query string and encode the parameters into the URL for the following resources:

Is there a configuration to remove the ? and date timestamp on the files like:

http://192.168.0.102/assets/topjs.js?1330103960

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a asset cache breaking mechanism in Rails. You can disable it in your `environment.rb` or the environment specific file with

`ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.cache_asset_timestamps = false`

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb#L517 as well.

Comment: Mmmh you're right but it brakes the app, it doesn't recognize the "t" in i18 gem :(

Comment: I don't see how this can be related. Do you get an exception? Which one?

Comment: `ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method 't' for #<ActionView::Base:0x10795b318>) on line #3 of app/views/news/_menu_tabs.html.haml:
1: %ul
2:   %li{:class => current_tab_selected('news', 'index') }
3:     = link_to t('tab.my_news'), root_path`

Comment: You may also set `ENV['RAILS_ASSET_ID'] = ''`.

Comment: Same error, I think there should be something on i18n that is needed let me take a look at the dependencies of the gem, thanks again.

Comment: Hi @iltempo it works just by putting this ENV['RAILS_ASSET_ID'] = '' on your environment file, thanks for your help!